# How should I go about changing my shower drain?

Tags: shower, drain

I have a shower drain that looks like this:

[image]

And the "drain cap", if that's even the right term, looks like this:

[image]

The drain cap is broken. I would like to replace the whole drain, but having no experience in DIY, that might be too big of a task.

So I might want to replace only the "cap", however I do not find any on the hardware store websites or amazon. Is my cap a special one or is it something standard? If it's pretty standard, what are the keywords I should be looking for when shopping for one?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a drain wrench similar to the one shown below.
[image: drain wrench]

Use it to unscrew the drain piece in the tub by turning it counter clockwise. Once you remove it, get a similar new drain and install it following any enclosed directions about sealing it.

Comment: Good answer but OP indicated they have no DIY experience. Probably not a repair for someone with no experience.

Comment: Yes, he did say that. Just maybe he'll realize it's pretty easy and attempt it.... after all, he has this site to fall back on. You, we, have helped people with much harder problems.

Comment: Interesting, so I just buy the wrench, unscrew the drain, insert the new drain, screw it in using the wrench and that's it? Or do I also need to also use some sort of "plumber putty"?

Comment: @maximedupre  That's where you "follow any enclosed directions". The drain usually comes with a large gasket that you place between the drain and tub.

Comment: You'll also need a pipe wrench or an adjustable wrench so you have enough leverage to turn the drain wrench. The body of the drain wrench is a hex so you can grab it with a pipe wrench or adjustable wrench.

Answer (score 2):

There are types of replacement stoppers that you can get that should screw into the threaded hole down in the drain. Some types have a knob on the top that allow you to push the stopper down to seal and pull up to drain. Another type works as a toggle. Push once to seal and then push again to let it raise up to drain.

The drain on a tub/shower in my house looks almost like that in your drain picture. The stopper is very much like this one:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NAOS03Z)*</sup>

The one shown comes with two sizes of the threaded stud that would screw into the hole down in your drain.

Comment: Oh yeah, that seems to be exactly the piece I need.

Comment: It seems like the thread is smaller than 3/8” or 5/16”....just bought this one and both little adapters are too large (or so it seems). Is there another standard size?

Comment: I guess this would be it: https://www.rona.ca/en/tip-toe-bath-tub-stopper-1-4-6784449

Comment: You might want to explore the actual size of the threaded hole in your drain basket. Consider a standard threaded bolt from a hardware store instead of plunking down significant money as an experiment.